# iOS 6 : Dynamic position of a picture, with UISlider

Tags: ios, image, dynamic, uislider

I'm developping an application in objective C, but I have a problem.

I want to move an image, on the y axe, with a UISlider, and so the images dynamic value.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a UISlider (Create IBOulet in your ViewController .h file, drag to UISlider if using IB or StoryBoard)

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISlider *theSlider;

1. Create imageView, you want to move with the slider (Create IBOulet in your ViewController .h file, drag to UIImageView if using IB or StoryBoard)

   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImage;
2. Now you have to create an action for the UISlider, to detect if the sliders value have changed (Create IBAction in your ViewController .h file, drag the action to the UISlider if using IB or StoryBoard and set the option to "value changed")
3. synthesize the properties in your .m file (@synthesize theImage, theSlider;)
4. set the sliders maximun an minimun values in fx. your viewDidload in your .m file: (    theSlider.maximumValue = 480;
   theSlider.minimumValue = -5;)
5. Do something like this in your "sliderValueChanged:(id)sender" action

   theImage.center = CGPointMake(theImage.center.x, [theSlider value]);

You have to adjust the sliders value, for your needs :)

Comment: Thank you :) Good luck with your app! :)

Comment: Thank you :) All is working, no warnings, i'm just going to see a friend designer and submit to apple ! :)